# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'x' property, but that property doesn't exist anywhere?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'll preface this by saying I'm new to SOAP, so I'm a little clueless about how to even begin debugging this.  I had built a script to get shipping rate information using SOAP calls, and it was working great.  A few weeks later, I come back, and I'm getting this error, instead of the expected rate quotes:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'CubicFeet' property

The thing that's maddening to me here, is that there is no `CubicFeet` property, anywhere.

Not in the API documentation from the shipping company, nowhere in my code... the request doesn't contain any `CubicFeet` value.

Searching through every single line of code in my entire website doesn't yield any results for `'CubicFeet'`.

It worked just fine before without any `CubicFeet` value.  But this is clearly failing on my end, it's never even sending the request to the web service.

How do I even begin to figure out what's going on here?  I'm happy to share code, but there's a ton of it, and I'm not even sure which piece could be causing the problem.  I just know that `'CubicFeet'` is a non-existent property in terms of what I've been doing and am trying to do, but suddenly I'm getting this error.

Please help, pulling my hair out over here.

Comment: I would suggest to contact the web services provider and find out if **CubicFeet** is a required field. Is it possible that WS API is not up-to-date? It sounds that the WS expect you to have CubicFeet in your SOAP request.

Comment: They just replied and said it is NOT a required property, so I'm still super confused.

Comment: http://b2b.freightquote.com/WebService/QuoteService.asmx?WSDL

Comment: It looks like despite what their customer support told me, it is an accepted property... allegedly optional but by not passing a value I was apparently unable to make a request.... thanks!

Comment: According to WSDL it is a required field: **<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CubicFeet" type="s:int"/>**